# Как сохранить ссылки на рисунки в sql и затем отобразить их в listview?

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Уважаемые господа программисты помогите решить следующую задачу.

Я хочу в базе данных хранить ссылки на изображения которые буду отображать в `listview`, я написал следующий код который работает не совсем корректно.

заполняю базу данных следующим образом, текст беру из `xml` файла, а на картинки которые лежат в `res/drawable` сохраняю адрес:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {    
  if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)&& (_xml.getName().equals("record"))){    
    String text = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);    
    cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, R.drawable.someImage + i);    
    cv.put(COLUMN_TEXT, text);    
    db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);    
    i++;    
  }
  eventType = _xml.next();
}
```

отображаю в `listview` так:

```
String[] from = new String[] { Base.COLUMN_IMG, Base.COLUMN_TEXT};    
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvText};    
scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursorAn, from, to);    
listview.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

На экране тестируемого устройства отображается все корректно, но в `LogCat` генерируются следующие ошибки:

```
Open file failed mFileDescriptor=-1, error=13 :Permission denied
Open file failed mFileDescriptor=-1, error=13 :Permission denied
Open file failed mFileDescriptor=-1, error=13 :Permission denied
```

Чем активней листаешь список тем больше ошибок....

Как можно эту ошибку победить, я в программировании новичок и уже кажется сломал голову как это решить.
Спасибо!

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то конструкция вида R.drawable.someImage - это переменная типа int. Если Вы к ней прибавляете i, то получаете просто другое число int.
Откройте файл R.java в папке gen и Вы увидите, что ic_launcher равен 0x7f020000 (лично у меня, у Вас что-то другое будет). А после сложения с i Вы будете пытаться открыть что-то другое. Вот отсюда и ошибки.

Comment: Да, совершенно верно типа int, к примеру адрес первого рисунка 2130837504 следующего 2130837505 и т.д. за счет того что я прибавляю i я и получаю адрес нужного мне рисунока. Да и приложение работает, но не дают мне покоя эти ошибки "Open file failed mFileDescriptor=-1, error=13 :Permission denied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно конечно... Никогда не занимался такими "изысками", но совершенно точно скажу одно, что полагаться на то что следующий рисунок будет иметь `id=idPrevious+1` я бы не стал. aapt, по-моему не гарантирует генерацию в последовательном порядке. Кроме того от сборки к сборке aapt не гарантирует постоянность значений идентификаторов (а они у вас уже лежат в БД)... Но если работает - то и слава б*гу

Касательно ошибки:

> Open file failed mFileDescriptor=-1, error=13 :Permission denied

Я думаю, что это возникает из-за того, чтобы ресурсы `readonly`, а адаптер их пытается читать в режиме `read-write` - вылечить это можно видимо только увидев исходники вашего курсора.

**Update**

Совсем забыл, возвращаясь собственно к самому вопросу - как хранить в SQL пути к файлам в ресурсе. Я бы сделал так:

1. Положить файлы не в каталог `/res`, а в каталог `/assets`
2. Хранить в БД путь к файлам в виде: `file:///android_asset/myfoldername/myfilename`

Comment: Когда я добавляю рисунки в res они сортируются в алфавитном порядке и id генерируется в порядке возрастания, по крайне мере у меня почему-то так и есть. Ну все же попробую сделать с помощью assets наверное так будет вернее, а "изысками" я занимаюсь потому как учусь и многого не знаю. Благодарю за подсказку.

Comment: Протестировал на asus google nexus 7 все работает без ошибок, так что дело в устройстве (до этого тестировал на Fly IQ440). Но все же буду переписывать приложение с другим подходом так как владельцы телефонов Fly (а может есть ещё какие-то китайские марки на которых будет некорректно работать) тоже должны иметь возможность пользоваться приложением. На fly стоит android 4.0.4 на asus 4.4.2 в принципе системы стоят не далеко друг от друга, а работают по разному, странно пока все это для меня.

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595665/) советуют хранить в БД имя файла (без расширения и пути), а потом в программе использовать это имя (`"picture1"`) так:

```
int resId =context.getResources().getIdentifier("picture1","drawable",context.getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(resId);
```